# Google Feed API alternatives

Tags: rss, rss-reader, google-feed-api

I am in the process of writing a RSS reader. I want the user to be able to search for RSS feeds on the web by keywords and subscribe to them.
Currently I am using Google Feed API which allow me to send text queries and receive all relevant RSS feeds from the web. Then I can take the feed URL and parse it for user reading / subscribing by saving it / share / and more..

Are there any other services like the one Google is offering?
I am looking to aggregate some more RSS feeds search providers so the application wont count only on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com), which I created. 
Our API is not identical to Google, but I believe we provide similar features, including JSON, realtime... etc.

Comment: I am looking for a service that I can search for feeds with, not one to subscribe or publish with... Am I missing something?